# What is the most efficient way to find 'gaps' in an array of date ranges?

Tags: javascript, date

Let's say I have an array of date ranges:

```
var date = [
    {
        start: '4/16/2021',
        end: '4/25/2021'
    },
    {
        start: '5/25/2021',
        end: '7/25/2021',
    },
    {
        start: '12/25/2021',
        end: '2/13/2022'
    }
];
```

What would be the most efficient way to find the dates that aren't covered within the date ranges, within a one year window? If the current date is 4/16/2021, the expected 'gaps' with these date ranges would be:

1. 4/26/2021 to 5/24/2021
2. 7/26/2021 to 12/24/2021
3. 2/14/2022 to 4/16/2022

Here is what I've tried so far. I know it's bad and there's gotta be a much more elegant solution.

```
var gapRange = 365;
var window = new GlideDate();
window.addDaysUTC(gapRange);

for (var x = 0; x < dates.length; x++) {

    var next = x + 1;
    var endPlusOne = new GlideDate();
    endPlusOne.setValue(date[x].end);
    endPlusOne.addDaysUTC(1);

    // There is only one date
    if (date.length == 1) {

        if (date[x].start > today) {
            gap.push({
                start: today,
                end: date[x].start,
            });
        }
        if (date[x].end < window) {
            gap.push({
                start: endPlusOne,
                end: window,
                status: 'upcoming'
            });
        }
        continue;
    }
    // This is the first date 
    if (x == 0) {
        if (date[x].start > today) {
            // This date starts after today
            var startMinusOne = new GlideDate();
            startMinusOne.setValue(date[x].start);
            startMinusOne.addDaysUTC(-1);
            gap.push({
                start: today,
                end: startMinusOne,
                status: 'upcoming'
            });
        }
    }
    // This is not the last date
    if (x < last) {
        if (endPlusOne.getDisplayValue() !== date[next].start.getDisplayValue() && date[x].end < date[next].start) {
            var startMinusOne = new GlideDate();
            startMinusOne.setValue(date[next].start);
            startMinusOne.addDaysUTC(-1);
            gap.push({
                start: endPlusOne,
                end: startMinusOne,
                state: 'vacant',
                status: 'upcoming'
            });
        }
    }
    // This is the last date 
    if (x == last) {
        if (endPlusOne < window) {
            gap.push({
                start: endPlusOne,
                end: window,
                status: 'upcoming'
            });
        }
    }
}

// There are no dates 
if (date.length == 0) {
    // Create a gap from today to the gap window 
    gap.push({
        start: today,
        end: window,
        status: 'current'
    });

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions that ask for most efficient way but don't show any attempts made typically mean *"code this for me"*. That's not how SO works. Objective is for you to show what you tried to solve your own issue and others help when it doesn't work as expected or you are stuck with a particular aspect. So...what have you tried?

Comment: Given a year and one range, how would you describe the gap ranges? Then generalize the approach by replacing "a year" with "some gap ranges"

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the welcome and tips. I have updated my post with what I have tried so far (not very pretty)

Comment: "Most efficient" by what critereon: amount of code? Processing time? Simplicity of algorithm? It's usually good to determine an algorithm first as almost certainly this has been done before and various algorithms and their relative efficiency and complexity are likely known. Then attempt to implement one that fits your criteria — perhaps one that is reasonably efficient but not too complex to code.